# Trying to disable/enable commands locally using json file

Tags: json, discord.py, nextcord

I'm trying to make 2 commands, One to enable commands and one to disable commands per guild, but I have problems as I don't have much experience with these json files,im trying to make it so when i disable a command it will check if the id is there and if the command is added already,and a command to enable the commmand back,where it checks for the guild id and command name

here is the code:

```
@client.command()
async def disablecommand(ctx, commandname):
    command = client.get_command(commandname)
    with open("Disabled_commands.json") as f:
      configData = json.load(f)
    disabledcommands = configData[f"{ctx.guild.id}"]
    if str(ctx.guild.id) in configData:            #check if the guild id is in list
      disabledcommands.append(command)
      if command in disabledcommands:            #check if command is already disabled
        await ctx.reply("command already disabled")
      else:            #if command is not disable
        disabledcommands.append(command)
        with open(f"{ctx.guild.id}", "r+") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            data["Disabled_commands"] = disabledcommands
            f.seek(0)
            f.write(json.dumps(data))
            f.truncate()

        await ctx.send("command has been disabled")
    else:            #if guild id is not in json file
        disabledcommands.append(command)

        with open(f"{ctx.guild.id}", "r+") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            data[f"{ctx.guild.id}"] = {}
            data["Disabled_commands"] = disabledcommands
            f.seek(0)
            f.write(json.dumps(data))
            f.truncate()


        await ctx.send("command has been disabled")

@client.command()
async def enablecommand(ctx, commandname):
    command = client.get_command(commandname)
    with open("Disabled_commands.json") as f:
      configData = json.load(f)
    disabledcommands = configData[f"{ctx.guild.id}"]
    if str(ctx.guild.id) in configData:            #check if server is in the list
     if command in disabledcommands:            #check if command is disabled
         disabledcommands.remove(command)

         with open("Disabled_commands.json", "r+") as f:
             data = json.load(f)
             data[f"{ctx.guild.id}"] = disabledcommands
             f.seek(0)
             f.write(json.dumps(data))
             f.truncate()


         await ctx.send("Command is now enabled")
     else:            #if command is enabled already
         await ctx.send("Command isnt disabled")
    else:             #if server isnt in the list
     await ctx.send("Command isnt disabled")
```

my json should look like this:

```
{"816726041673990214":{"ping","mute","ban"},"786631236838883400":{"troll","thing","ping"}}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting with your code?

Comment: at some point i was getting "Command raised an exception: KeyError: '816726041673990214'"
but now i get "Command raised an exception: JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 31 (char 30)"

Comment: Which line is 31?

Comment: tbh,i dont know

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that your json is invalid, and so the json decoder raises an error. The problem with your json is that you use `{}` around `"ping","mute","ban"`, but `"ping","mute","ban"` is a list, so you would have to use `[]` around it. Your fixed json should look like this:

```
{"816726041673990214":["ping","mute","ban"],"786631236838883400":["troll","thing","ping"]}
```

Comment: i did that and now i get this error "Command raised an exception: KeyError: '816726041673990214' "

Comment: @RainbowGuy This line here is what is getting the error I think, it needs to be str(ctx.guild.id).
```
disabledcommands = configData[f"{ctx.guild.id}"]
```
See?

Comment: i still get the same error

Comment: Can you add the entire error message, including the line in which the error occured?